# Resizing partition where Ubuntu is installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm having trouble with resizing partitions. To test the relationship between me and Ubuntu, I installed it on a dual boot with the Ubuntu partition being 64 GB.

But now I regret I did 64 GB only, so I want to make another partition that is bigger. Is it possible to just move Ubuntu from one partition to another? Sorry if this is a stupid question. Also English isn't my language. :)

Note: In the following screenshot, green is where I have my stuff, red is the one I have Ubuntu, and non-colored is where I want to install Ubuntu (ignore the size of it, I typed it wrong).

[image: partition scheme]

Comment: This looks like a screenshot of Windows` disk and partition tools.  Don't use that to change your Ubuntu partitions!

Answer (score 2):

You can boot the system with a live USB and use gparted to enlarge the partition.

Take sensible precautions first - back up everything you cannot afford to lose in case you make an error or a mishap occurs.